# Windows Phone 7 - OrderedDictionary / alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, collections

I'm completely new to C#, so I'm about to make a horrible attempt at my own version of an OrderedDictionary unless someone can suggest an alternative.

I need to be able to access my elements by array index, retaining the order they were added, and I also will be frequently updating individual elements using their key.

1. Is there a collection that allows this on the phone?
2. If I keep a List and Dictionary will they both be pointing to the same item or is there some kind of pointer thing I have to do?:

   ```
   Item i = new Item();
   list.Add(i);
   dict.Add("key", i);
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a List and a Dictionary is probably a good option actually. The "pointer thing" that you're talking about happens by default for Objects in .NET (any class and/or structure). All objects in .NET are passed around *by reference*.

So, if you use:

```
Item i = new Item();
list.Add(i);
dict.Add("key",i);
Console.WriteLine(list.Last() == dict["key"]);
```

Your output will be "true".

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation (comes from the [open source OpenNETCF Extensions library](http://oncfext.codeplex.com/)):

```
public class OrderedDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> m_dictionary;
    private List<TValue> m_list = new List<TValue>();
    private object m_syncRoot = new object();

    public OrderedDictionary()
    {
        m_dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public OrderedDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        m_dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (m_syncRoot)
        {
            m_dictionary.Add(key, value);
            m_list.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public TValue this[int index]
    {
        get { return m_list[index]; }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return m_dictionary[key]; }
    }

    public int Count 
    {
        get { return m_dictionary.Count; } 
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection Keys 
    {
        get { return m_dictionary.Keys; } 
    }

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection Values 
    {
        get { return m_dictionary.Values; } 
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (m_syncRoot)
        {
            m_dictionary.Clear();
            m_list.Clear();
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return m_dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value)
    {
        return m_dictionary.ContainsValue(value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (m_syncRoot)
        {
            m_list.Insert(index, value);
            m_dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(TKey key)
    {
        lock (m_syncRoot)
        {
            if (ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var existing = m_dictionary[key];
                m_list.Remove(existing);
                m_dictionary.Remove(key);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty good. Unfortunately, it offers no quick way to get the index for a particular item. Also, it doesn't support `RemoveAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I won't suggest using OrderedDictionary, since it's a non-generic container.

However, if you just want to use it like always. You can port Mono's version of OrderedDictionary.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Collections.Specialized/OrderedDictionary.cs

Here's some tips if you want to port this:

1. Remove any unavailable interface
2. Remove serialization-related code
3. Replace ArrayList with `List<object>`
4. Replace Hashtable with `Dictionary<object, object>`